# Gulp watch task not running karma jasmine tests

Tags: jasmine, gulp, karma-jasmine, gulp-watch

I'm trying to setup a gulp watch task to run all test under a set of folder, I can get the gulp tasks to run successful:

```
[10:20:15] Finished 'karma' after 5.86 s
[10:20:15] Starting 'default'...
[10:20:15] Finished 'default' after 9.45 ms
```

But no notification of any test passing?

Here is my karma.config:

```
var webpack = require("webpack"),
path = require("path");

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine"],
    files: [
        "./App/src/tests/**/*.js"
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        "./App/src/tests/**/*.js": ["webpack"]
    },
    webpack: {
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.js$/, loader: "jsx-loader" }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin([
                new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
            ])
        ],
        resolve: {
            root: [path.join(__dirname, "./bower_components"), path.join(__dirname, "./src")]
        }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
        noInfo: true
    },
    plugins: [
        require("karma-webpack"),
        require("karma-jasmine"),
        require("karma-chrome-launcher")
    ],
    reporters: ["dots"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    singleRun: false
});
};
```

Here is my karma.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('gulp-karma');

 function handleError(err) {
 this.emit('end');
 }

 gulp.task('karma', function() {
 return gulp
     .src('./App/src/tests/**/*.js')
     .pipe(karma({
         configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
         action: 'run'
     }))
     .on("error", handleError);

 });
```

Gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
requireDir = require('require-dir');

requireDir('./gulp-tasks');

gulp.task('default', ['browserify','css','karma'], function () {
gulp.watch('../App/src/**/*.js', ['browserify']);
 gulp.watch('../App/src/**/*.css', ['css']);
gulp.watch('../App/src/tests/**/*.js', ['karma']);
});
```